# Is it possible to do usual atomic INSERT operation but update Indexes asynchronously?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-indexes

indexes make read fast but write slower. But why can't you have single writes and have db add indexes asynchronously with time, also cache in the INSERT until it's indexed?

Is there any database like that?

Comment: Database IO performance is not really about computational-complexity - it’s about the fact that IO bandwidth is a bottleneck, and small random IO (on spinning-rust drives especially) is best to be avoided by applications.

Comment: Indexes *need* to be updated atomically with table data otherwise you’d break the ACID model. Consider that many RDBMS mirror data in indexes (the `INCLUDE` clause) precisely to avoid table reads - or to implement columnar stores. That’s why they can’t be updated “asynchronously” as you say - because then a second query that runs after your first query (that only uses an index-stored column) would be reading incorrect/stale/old data, which you really don’t want,

Comment: @Dai can you give an example for "a second query that runs after your first query"

Comment: First query: `INSERT INTO tbl ( PK, A, B ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 )`. Second query: `SELECT A, B FROM tbl WHERE PK = 1`. (Remember that the term "query" is often used to describe DML statements, not just `SELECT` queries - especially as DML statements can include nested queries, e.g. a `MERGE INTO x USING y` statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer:

> indexes make read fast but write slower

That's an oversimplification and it's also misleading.

Indexes make data *lookups* faster because the DBMS doesn't need to do a table-scan to find rows matching a predicate (the `WHERE` part of a query). Indexes don't make "reads" any faster (that's entirely dependent on the characteristics of your disk IO) and when used improperly they can sometimes even make queries slower (for reasons I won't get into).

I want to stress that **the additional cost of writing to a single index, or even multiple indexes, when executing a DML statement (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE/etc`) is negligible**, really! (In actuality: foreign-key constraints are a much bigger culprit - and I note you can practically eliminate the cost of foreign-key constraint checking *by adding additional indexes*!). Indexes are primarily implemented using B-trees (a B-tree is essentially like a binary-tree, except rather than each node having only 2 children it can have *many* children because each tree-node comes with unused space for all those child node pointers, so inserting into the middle of a B-tree won't require data to be moved-around on-disk unlike with other kinds of trees, like a heap-tree).

[Consider this QA where a Postgres user (like yourself) reports inserting 10,000 rows into a table. Without an index it took 78ms, with an index it took 84ms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96223/postgres-insert-performance-with-indexes), that's only a 7.5% increase, which at that scale (6ms!) is so small it may as well be a rounding error or caused by IO scheduling. That should be proof enough it shouldn't be something you should worry about without actual hard data showing it's a problem for you and your application.

I assume you have this negative impression about indexes [after reading an article like this one](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert), which certainly gives the impression that "indexes are bad" - but while the points mentioned in that article are not wrong, there's a *LOT* of problems with that article so you shouldn't take it dogmatically. (I'll list my concerns with that article in the footer).

> But why can't you have single writes and have db add indexes asynchronously with time

By this I assume you mean you'd like a DMBS to do a single-row `INSERT` by simply appending a new record to the end of a table and then immediately returning and then at an arbitrary point later the DBMS' housekeeping system would update the indexes afterwards.

The problem with that is that it breaks the A, C, and I parts of the [the A.C.I.D. model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Indexes are used for more than just avoiding table-scans: they're also used to store copies of table data for the benefit of queries that would use the index and which also need (for example) a small subset of the table's data, this significantly reduces disk reads. For this reason, RDBMS (and ISO SQL) allow indexes to include non-indexed data using the `INCLUDES` clause.

Consider this scenario:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Owners ON cars ( ownerId ) INCLUDE ( colour );
CREATE INDEX IX_Names  ON people ( name ) INCLUDE ( personId, hairColour );

GO;

SELECT
    people.name,
    people.hairColour,
    cars.colour
FROM
    cars
    INNER JOIN people ON people.personId = cars.ownerId
WHERE
    people.name LIKE 'Steve%'
```

The above query will *not* need to read either the `cars` or `people` tables on-disk. The DBMS will be able to fully answer the query using data only in the index - which is great because indexes tend to exist in a small number of *pages* on-disk which tend to be in proximal-locality which is good for performance because it means it will use *sequential IO* which scales much better than *random IO*.

The RDBMS will perform a string-prefix index-scan of the `people.IX_Names` index to get all of the `personId` (and `hairColour`) values, then it will look-up those `personId` values in the `cars.IX_Owners` index and be able to get the `car.colour` from the copy of the data inside the `IX_Owners` index without needing to read the tables directly.

---

Now, assuming that another database client has just completed inserted a load of records into the `cars` and/or `people` table with a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` just for good measure, and the RDMBS uses your idea of only updating indexes later *whenever it feels like it*, then if that same database client re-runs the query from above it would return stale data (i.e. **wrong** data) because the query uses the index, but the index is old.

---

In addition to using index tree nodes to store copies of table data to avoid non-proximal disk IO, many RDBMS also use index-trees to store *entire copies* - even multiple copies of table data, to enable other scenarios, such as [columnar data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) and [indexed-VIEWs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) - both of these features absolutely require that indexes are updated atomically with table data.

> Is there any database like that?

Yes, they exist - but they're not widely used (or they're niche) because for the vast majority of applications it's entirely undesirable behaviour for the reasons described above.

There are *distributed databases* that are designed around *eventual consistency*, but clients (and entire application code) needs to be designed with that in-mind, and it's a huge PITA to have to redesign a data-centric application to support eventual-consistency which is why you only really see them being used in truly massive systems (like Facebook, Google, etc) where availability (uptime) is more important than users seeing stale-data for a few minutes.

---

Footnote:

Regarding this article: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert

> The number of indexes on a table is the most dominant factor for insert performance. The more indexes a table has, the slower the execution becomes. The insert statement is the only operation that cannot directly benefit from indexing because it has no where clause.

I disagree. I'd argue that foreign-key constraints (and triggers) are far *more likely* to have a larger detrimental effect on DML operations.

> Adding a new row to a table involves several steps. First, the database must find a place to store the row. For a regular heap table—which has no particular row order—the database can take any table block that has enough free space. This is a very simple and quick process, mostly executed in main memory. All the database has to do afterwards is to add the new entry to the respective data block.

I agree with this.

> If there are indexes on the table, the database must make sure the new entry is also found via these indexes. For this reason it has to add the new entry to each and every index on that table. The number of indexes is therefore a multiplier for the cost of an insert statement.

This is true, but I don't know if I agree that it's a "multiplier" of the cost of an insert.

For example, consider a table with hundreds of `nvarchar(1000)` columns and several `int` columns - and there's separate indexes for each `int` column (with no `INCLUDE` columns). If you're inserting 100x megabyte-sized rows all-at-once (using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` statement) the cost of updating those `int` indexes is very likely to require much less IO than the table data.

> Moreover, adding an entry to an index is much more expensive than inserting one into a heap structure because the database has to keep the index order and tree balance. That means the new entry cannot be written to any block—it belongs to a specific leaf node. Although the database uses the index tree itself to find the correct leaf node, it still has to read a few index blocks for the tree traversal.

I strongly disagree with this, especially the first sentence: "adding an entry to an index is much more expensive than inserting one into a heap structure".

Indexes in RDBMS today are invariably based on B-trees, *not binary-trees* or heap-trees. B-trees are essentially like binary-trees except each node has built-in space for dozens of child node pointers and B-trees are only rebalanced when a node fills its internal child pointer list, so a B-tree node insert will be considerably cheaper than the article is saying because each node will have plenty of empty space for a new insertion without needing to re-balance itself or any other relatively expensive operation (besides, [DBMS *can and do* index maintenance separately and independently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/rebuild-index-task-maintenance-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) of any DML statement).

The article *is* correct about how the DBMS will need to traverse the B-tree to find the node to insert into, but index nodes are efficently arranged on-disk, such as keeping related nodes in the same disk page which minimizes index IO reads (assuming they aren't already loaded into memory first). If an index tree is too big to store in-memory the RDBMS can always keep a "meta-indexes" in-memory so it could potentially *instantly* find the correct B-tree index without needing to traverse the B-tree from the root.

> Once the correct leaf node has been identified, the database confirms that there is enough free space left in this node. If not, the database splits the leaf node and distributes the entries between the old and a new node. This process also affects the reference in the corresponding branch node as that must be duplicated as well. Needless to say, the branch node can run out of space as well so it might have to be split too. In the worst case, the database has to split all nodes up to the root node. This is the only case in which the tree gains an additional layer and grows in depth.

In practice this isn't a problem, because the RDBMS's index maintenance will ensure there's sufficient free space in each index node.

> The index maintenance is, after all, the most expensive part of the insert operation. That is also visible in Figure 8.1, “Insert Performance by Number of Indexes”: the execution time is hardly visible if the table does not have any indexes. Nevertheless, adding a single index is enough to increase the execute time by a factor of a hundred. Each additional index slows the execution down further.

I feel the article is being dishonest by suggesting (implying? stating?) that index-maintenance happens with every DML. This is not true. This may have been the case with some early dBase-era databases, but this is certainly not the case with modern RDBMS like [Postgres](https://rcoh.me/posts/postgres-indexes-under-the-hood/), MS SQL Server, Oracle and others.

> Considering insert statements only, it would be best to avoid indexes entirely—this yields by far the best insert performance.

Again, this claim in the article *is not wrong*, but it's basically saying if you want a clean and tidy house you should get rid of all of your possessions. Indexes are a fact of life.

> However tables without indexes are rather unrealistic in real world applications. You usually want to retrieve the stored data again so that you need indexes to improve query speed. Even write-only log tables often have a primary key and a respective index.

Indeed.

> Nevertheless, the performance without indexes is so good that it can make sense to temporarily drop all indexes while loading large amounts of data—provided the indexes are not needed by any other SQL statements in the meantime. This can unleash a dramatic speed-up which is visible in the chart and is, in fact, a common practice in data warehouses.

Again, with modern RDBMS this isn't necessary. If you do a batch insert then a RDBMS won't update indexes until *after* the table-data has finished being modified, as a batch index update is cheaper than many individual updates. Similarly I *expect* that multiple DML statements and queries inside an explicit `BEGIN TRANSACTION` *may* cause an index-update deferral provided no subsequent query in the transaction relies on an updated index.

But my biggest issue with that article is that **the author is making these bold claims about detrimental IO performance without providing any citations or even benchmarks they've run themselves**. It's even more galling that they posted a bar-chart with arbitrary numbers on, again, without any citation or raw benchmark data and instructions for how to reproduce their results. Always demand citations and evidence from anything you read making claims: because the only claims anyone should accept without evidence are logical axioms - and a quantitative claim about database index IO cost is not a logical axiom :)

Comment: First, I'd like to thanks a lot for this write up, for new comers it's immensely useful to see past one liners and insights like this. My takeaway is that to determine whether indexes are causing slow down at write depends on what is being updated and even then one need to run benchmarks. One follow up question: "you can practically eliminate the cost of foreign-key constraint checking by adding additional indexes" This is saying add index in foregin table on id, correct?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer For `INSERT` operations: yes - however those indexes *already exist* (primary-keys are always indexed in modern RDBMS) so you don't need to add them yourself (unless you have a table without a PK, but that would just be silly). It's mainly `DELETE` (and some kinds of `UPDATE`) operations on a principal table (PK table) where having indexes on FK columns in dependent tables (FK tables) is necessary for decent IO perf.

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL GIN indexes, there is the fastupdate feature.  This stores new index entries into a unordered unconsolidated area waiting for some other process to file them away into the main index structure.  But this doesn't directly match up with what you want.  It is mostly designed so that the index updates are done in bulk (which can be more IO efficient), rather than in the background.  Once the unconsolidated area gets large enough, then a foreground process might take on the task of filing them away, and it can be hard to tune the settings in a way to get this to always be done by a background process instead of a foreground process.  And it only applies to GIN indexes. (With the use of the btree_gin extension, you can create GIN indexes on regular scalar columns rather than the array-like columns it usually works with.)  While waiting for the entries to be consolidated, every query will have to sequential scan the unconsolidated buffer area, so delaying the updates for the sake of INSERT can come at a high cost for SELECTs.

There are more general techniques to do something like this, such as [fractal tree indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_tree_index).  But these are not implemented in PostgreSQL, and wherever they are implemented they seem to be proprietary.